# Add a placeholder to several input fields (with the same class) using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML form with 4 inputs fields inside it. All these input fields have the same class and ID, the only differences are the "divs" surounding the inputs.

- One form is in the header the other one in the content, and inside each of them, one field is a username field to login, and the other one to register.

  ```
  <div class=theheader>
  <h1> The Header</h1>

  <div class="fullform">

  <div class="container register">
    <div class="form_group  required">
      <input class="input_text" id="username_field"  name="username" size="30" value="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container login">
      <div class="form_group">
        <input class="input_text" id="username_field" name="username" size="30" type="text" >
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>

  <div class=thecontent>
  <h1> Form Content</h1>

  <div class="fullform">

  <div class="container register">
    <div class="form_group  required">
      <input class="input_text" id="username_field"  name="username" size="30" value="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container login">
      <div class="form_group">
        <input class="input_text" id="username_field" name="username" size="30" type="text" >
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  ```

Here is an example of what it looks like : http://jsfiddle.net/M6R7K/78/.

I need to add a placeholder inside each of these fields, but the tricky thing is, I don't have any direct access to this HTML code, because this one is automatically generated by a third party plugin. So I can only add javascript or css, using the existing classes and ids.

So I used the javascript :

> document.getElementById("username_field").setAttribute("placeholder", "Username");

And it has indeed add the correct placeholder in the correct field. The problem is, it only add the placeholder in the 1st field found, not all of them. Even if I add several lines of javascript.

So the question : How to fill up all these field with a placeholder without touching the HTML code ? (With javascript or anything else) And at the best possible, having a different placeholder for each field ? (One needs to be "username and email", and the other one "username" only). We should be able to use the classes of the div's, just like we can do in CSS. But I wasn't able to figure it out.

Thanks !

Comment: First thing to do is fix the re-use of "id" values. The "id" attribute needs to be a unique identifier, and any value can only be used once on a page.

Comment: How are we supposed to correctly specify which `placeholder` belongs in whichever element, there doesn't appear to be any attribute by which to determine the appropriate placeholder, since they all seem to share each of their attributes.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the feedback. Yes I know that the re-use of the ID's is not good, unfortunately I can't touch the HTML code. Maybe is there a way to change the ID's by javascript ? (Let's say add an incremented number in the end of each input's ID field). Or other thing I was thinking, anyway to use the "divs" around the inputs to specify witch of the ID's we want to fill up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to find the solution, using the "attr" function, and the Jquery framework.

This is the function that I applied to each of the inputs, in order to create a unique placeholder (example for the 1st field) :

```
$(".theheader .register input").attr('placeholder', 'Username Header')
```

This code allows to retrieve the DIV CLASS of each input field, and apply a customized field.

So for my example, it would be this :

```
$(".theheader .register input").attr('placeholder', 'Username Header')
$(".theheader .login input").attr('placeholder', 'Username or Email Header');
$(".thecontent .register input").attr('placeholder', 'Username Content');
$(".thecontent .login input").attr('placeholder', 'Username or Email Content');
```

And each field has his customized placeholder !

Here is the result : https://jsfiddle.net/3ddo465n/9/

Thank you all for the contribution !

Answer (score 3):

Your code set placeholder one of them. Standard don't define which of them will get the placeholder because standard forces you tou use ID only once per page. You need to set placeholders for all elements with `input_text` class. You can do it by array with placeholders and iterating fields: In each iteration set i-th placeholder from array by this code

```
var placeholders = ["Username", "Email", "Phone", "Credit card"]
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].setAttribute("placeholder", placeholders[i]);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/M6R7K/81/

The best practice is set placeholders normally in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I can't find any better solution, I'll use this one to fill them all up with the same placeholder, best solution posted so far. Is there anyway to change the ID's by incrementing them with numbers using javascript, and then use them ? Or use the DIV's arround ?

Comment: You can incrementally change IDs by JS i don't know where it can be useful. Just replace or add after my third line `elements[i].id = "input_text" + i`. Then you get elements with IDs `input_text1`, `input_text2`, `input_text3`, ....  ID is unique identifier which is set to exactly one element in page. If you have 4 similar inputs It is not good idea to accesing they by ID.

Comment: I edited answer with ideal solution by setting placeholder natively in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the code but it hasn't increase the ID's of the inputs on page load :(
(The reason why it would be useful, is if the fields have a different ID's (lets say username_field1 / username_field2), I would then be able to use these unique ID's to set-up a unique placeholder for each of them.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/gtbtzhja/1/ there is no ID, no class and placeholder there is.

Comment: Are you sure about the fiddlle ? I'm seeing this code : 

<div class="container register">
    <div class="form_group  required">
        <input placeholder="Username" name="username" size="30" value="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>, one field with no javascript.

Comment: Yes but you have set the placeholder directly in the HTML not by javascript right ? I don't have any control over the HTML code, that's why I need to have a javascript for it, with a different placeholder for each field. So that's why I said that maybe, using javascript, there is a way to change the ID's (maybe add a number in the end of it by incrementation), so the ID's can be unique and therefore have a unique placeholder. Here is what it looks like with your code : http://jsfiddle.net/M6R7K/80/, all the placeholders are "username", the desired result is "username" / "name" / "email", etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has worked well :). I have been able to find a better solution using jquery, it adapts better to a more complex form, that has the right div's around, which was my case, I have been able to use the DIVs class to create the right placeholders. I'v published my answer on the bottom. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot use the same id for more then one element.

Second: try to use as input name attribute meaningful values. If you cannot touch the HTML you can always use the index parameter inside the forEach loop, this could be an idea. Another idea could be to look for the root element in order to distinguish the input fields.

I tried to do for you, right to give you an idea on how to solve your problem:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("input_text")).forEach(function(currentValue, index) {
    currentValue.setAttribute("placeholder", currentValue.getAttribute('name'));
  });
}
```

```html
<div class=theheader>
    <h1> The Header</h1>

    <div class="fullform">

        <div class="container register">
            <div class="form_group  required">
                <input class="input_text" id="username_field1"  name="username" size="30" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container login">
            <div class="form_group">
                <input class="input_text" id="username_field2" name="password" size="30" type="text" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=thecontent>
    <h1> Form Content</h1>

    <div class="fullform">

        <div class="container register">
            <div class="form_group  required">
                <input class="input_text" id="username_field3"  name="email" size="30" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container login">
            <div class="form_group">
                <input class="input_text" id="username_field4" name="other" size="30" type="text" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is indeed a very good idea ! Unfortunately, I can't possibly change the "name" of the inputs and have meaningfull values to them, I have no control over these fields. And since the website is not in english, it absolutely needs to be a custom text. Your answer made me think though, in the HTML you provided, you have "id="username_field1", "id="username_field1" etc. Is there any way to make that happen through javascript ? (Adding a number or so, incremented, in the end of the ID's, using a code ?). Then I'd be able to have unique ID's